# Is there a shorter way to import classes of a submodule?

Tags: python

Currently, I do this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
keras = tf.contrib.keras
Sequential = keras.models.Sequential
Dense = keras.layers.Dense
Dropout = keras.layers.Dropout
Flatten = keras.layers.Flatten
Conv2D = keras.layers.Conv2D
MaxPooling2D = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
keras = tf.contrib.keras
from tf.contrib.keras import (Sequential, Dense, Dropout, Flatten,
                              Conv2D, MaxPooling2D)
```

but when I try this I get

```
ImportError: No module named tf.contrib.keras
```

Is there a shorter way than the first code block to import those classes?

### Other tries

```
>>> from tensorflow.contrib.keras import (Sequential, Dense, Dropout, Flatten)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Sequential
```

Nr 2

```
>>> import tensorflow
>>> from tensorflow.contrib.keras.models import Sequential
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named models
>>> tensorflow.contrib.keras.models.Sequential
<class 'tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras.models.Sequential'>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to import using the actual name of the `tensorflow` module, not the `tf` alias you used for it:

Second, the package structure of `tensorflow.contrib.keras` is kind of weird. The names

```
tensorflow.contrib.keras.models
tensorflow.contrib.keras.layers
```

are actually aliases for the more deeply nested modules

```
tensorflow.contrib.keras.api.keras.models
tensorflow.contrib.keras.api.keras.layers
```

and the way these aliases are created doesn't allow you to use `from` imports to import their contents. You can use the "real" names directly:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.api.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.api.keras.layers import (
        Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D)
```

(There's even more aliasing here - the `tensorflow.contrib.keras.api.keras.*` modules pull most of their contents from `tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras` - but we don't need to worry about that.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
```

Comment: Care to share the exception?

Comment: See "Nr 2" in my question.

Comment: You don't need to first import tensorflow, that might be causing it just copy these two lines and only these

Comment: No, that is not the problem.